# How to submit via AJAX multiple values/array?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a **HTML** table which is *editable/dynamic*. Please see table below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="txt_row_{{ $records[$i]["row_id"] }}" type="hidden" value="{{$records[$i]["row_id"]}}" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="is_workingday_row_{{ $records[$i]["row_id"] }}" checked /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input id="txt_row_{{ $records[$i]["row_id"] }}" type="hidden" value="{{$records[$i]["row_id"]}}" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="is_workingday_row_{{ $records[$i]["row_id"] }}" checked /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, how can I loop thru the entire table to get the values/changes thru jQuery and submit it via **AJAX** to a **PHP** script? Can you at least point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: show what you have tried so far so we can see were it needs improvement

Comment: See the [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method for converting a set of inputs into data for AJAX.

Comment: If you are in form you can use serialsize to get all values.

Comment: if i totally understood your problem, You are trying to send all the data to your server when you submit the form correct?

Comment: add the name attr for all checkbox elements as array like name = checkdata[], and use the $(form).serialize() method to send the form data with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Ronald you can use form instead of table but if you are using table you have to use jquery each function to get all inputs value and create object of these values and after that you can send this through ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allInputs = $('table').find('input');
    var obj = {};
    $(allInputs).each(function(){
        var key = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();
        obj[key] = value
    });
    console.log(obj);

    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var allInputs = $('table').find('input');
 var obj = {};
 $(allInputs).each(function(){
  var key = $(this).attr('name');
  var value = $(this).val();
  obj[key] = value
 });
 console.log(obj);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="txt_row_1" type="hidden" name="txt_row_1" value="record1" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="is_workingday_row_1" id="is_workingday_row_1" checked /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input id="txt_row_2" name="txt_row_2" type="hidden" value="record2" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="is_workingday_row_2" id="is_workingday_row_2" checked /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```